# Wrong onselect display ? Angular 2+

Tags: javascript, angular, forms

When I select an option instead of showing me the name it shows me the id. That's because I bind [value] = "option.id". I'm sending an id to the server and want to show name.

```
          <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
            <input
            matInput
            placeholder="Pretrazite proizvod koji zelite naruciti samo kucajte pocetna slova"
            formControlName="id"
            [matAutocomplete] = "auto"
            >
            <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete" >
                  <mat-option *ngFor="let option of allProducts; let i = index"   [value]="option.id"   (onSelectionChange)="getPosts(i)">
                {{ option.name }}
              </mat-option>
            </mat-autocomplete>
          </mat-form-field>



  getProducts() {
    this.product.getAllProducts().subscribe((data: any) => {
     this.allProducts = data.products;
     console.log(data.products);
    });
  }
```

I also have (onSelectionChange) = "getPosts (i)" function

```
  getPosts(index){ 
    this.selectedProduct = index;
  }
```

My question is how do I forward the id and display the name in mat-autocomplete-mat-option options.
I suppose this onchange is my function, the problem is that I have dynamic fields
Looking my other code

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.getProducts();
    this.form = this.fb.group({
      address: [null],
      phone: [null],
      city: [null],
      data: this.fb.array([this.createContact()])
    }); 
    this.contactList = this.form.get('data') as FormArray;
  }

  createContact(): FormGroup {
    return this.fb.group({
      id: [this.selectedProduct], 
      quantity: [null]
    });
```

In case you need the whole code, ask me, but I didn't want to overwhelm you with a lot of code.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this, it should help you:

```
<mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete" >
              <mat-option *ngFor="let option of allProducts; let i = index"   [value]="selectedProduct.name"   (onSelectionChange)="getPosts(option)">
            {{ option.name }}
          </mat-option>
        </mat-autocomplete>
```

Comment: Again when I select the option it shows me the number. What the number means to the user

Comment: can you create a jsfiddle ?

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6hvqpk
This is only code viewer.
I have very much code to do to make everything work

Comment: What is  [value]="selectedProduct.name"  ?

Comment: saw that in your getPosts method you are just setting position instead im setting the selected object, thereby displaying the name and while sending the request you can use `selectedProduct.id`

Comment: I am little confused. But again no work.  When I select the option, the field will be blank. When I send the value is noting