# How to display a name but take the values of some other property from the object from mat-autocomplete select? Angular- Angular Material

Tags: javascript, angular, forms, angular-material

I spent a lot of time solving this problem and failed. I want to select to display the name and get the id. The problem is, as soon as a value is selected, the number (id) of that value is displayed. My code:

```
          <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
            <input
            matInput
            placeholder="Search your product"
            formControlName="id"
            [matAutocomplete] = "auto">
            <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete" > 
                  <mat-option    *ngFor="let option of allProducts; let i = index"   [value]="option.id"   >
                {{ option.name }}
              </mat-option>
            </mat-autocomplete>
          </mat-form-field>
```

I tried to create a function (onSelectionChange) but could not display the name and take the value as (id)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Wrong onselect display ? Angular 2+](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59120701/wrong-onselect-display-angular-2)

Comment: Unfortunately not. I've been trying to solve this problem for a couple of days now and I can't manage it :(

Answer (score 1):

Well, you have to use the input function of auto-complete called `displayWith`.

[you can find the solution to your problem in this link here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44234290/how-to-display-using-displaywith-in-autocomplete-material2)

plus I 've made a stackblitz example for you to simplify it more.

[Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-otood2?file=src/app/autocomplete-simple-example.html)

to describe the solution:

you have to add to your autocomplete component an input called displayWith

```
<mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete" [displayWith]="checkValue">
```

and then in your component you have to create the function checkValue

```
checkValue(value: any) {
// here you can get your id or whatever you want
console.log(value)
}
```

then you have to add to your mat option the value and give it your whole object as value

```
<mat-option *ngFor="let option of options" [value]="option" >
    {{option.name}}
</mat-option>
```

[Please check the stackblitz example for more details](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-otood2?file=src/app/autocomplete-simple-example.html)

Comment: I am copy/paste solution from internet 

  displayFn(item) {
    return this.matAutocomplete.options.filter(x => x.value === item).map(x => x.viewValue)[0] ? this.matAutocomplete.options.filter(x => x.value === item).map(x => x.viewValue)[0] : item;
  }

  patchFormData() {
    this.form.controls['id'].setValue(1);
  }

Comment: check this https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-otood2?file=src/app/autocomplete-simple-example.html

Comment: okey try to help me here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59129383/how-to-configure-date-picker-angular-to-send-me-rfc-2822-format-angula-6-dat